# Anchor tag not working even with z-index changed

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor

The simple anchor tag is not following the link even when it is brought to the top of the z-index

HTML

```
<a id="about" href="http://google.com">About</a>
```

CSS

```
#about {
font-size: 9vw;
color: red;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Post the rest of the code, what you have there is fine.

Comment: Can you show your other code that is included with it?

Comment: I think that because z-index just works with some `position`, I think issue in it. Try add `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change element's `position` property to another value than default `static` in order to make `z-index` have an effect.

> The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of
>   elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically
>   closer to you. z-index only effects elements that have a position
>   value other than static (the default).

Reference: [Css-Tricks - z-index](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)